# Mapping unrelated collections into one

Tags: c#, automapper

I have an class with two collections of different unrelated types

```
public class Entity
{
    ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map this using AutoMapper to another class with one collection

```
public class DTO {
    ICollection<FooBar>
}
```

I configure the mappings respectivitly for the two entity types into the Dto type.

```
.CreateMap<Foo, FooBar>()
.CreateMap<Bar, FooBar>()
```

How can I configure the mapping Entity -> Dto so that the two collections Foos and Bars is merged into Foobars?

If I configure them seperatly as this

```
.CreateMap<Entity, Dto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FooBars, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Foos))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FooBars, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Bars))
```

FooBars is set twice and hence overwritten by the second collection.

The question [Automapper - Multi object source and one destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544133/automapper-multi-object-source-and-one-destination) show ways to merge the two collections inte one in different ways, all of them requires multiple method calls when doing the actual mapping. I want to configure this so I can do the mapping by simply writing

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Entity, Dto>(entities);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That you need is a [custom value resolver](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html):

```
public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver<Source, Destination, int>
{
    public int Resolve(Entity entity
        , DTO dto
        , ICollection<FooBar> fooBars
        , ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // Here you should convert from entity Foos and Bars
        // to ICollection<FooBar> and concat them.
    }
}
```

Then at the setup of AutoMapper you should use the above custom resolver:

```
// other code
.CreateMap<Entity, Dto>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.FooBars, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());
```

Comment: When you say **Here you should convert from entity Foos and Bars** do you mean manually or is there a way to use the mapping configuration to map the objects ?    I cant figure out how to do a AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Entity, Dto>(entities); from within a custom resolver.

Comment: @DaImTo I mean manually. I am not aware, if we can use the mapping configuration to map the objects.