# Map multiple different models into single View Model - AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I am trying to map multiple Userprofile models into a single viewModel. At a time only one user data will be mapped.

In the below code snippet I mentioned the use case that I already tried.
Also, I try to `AutoMapper.Map<source,target>` but didn't work for me.

//This is one FarmerUser Model

```
 public partial class FarmerProfileModel
    {      
    public long FarmerId { get; set; }

    public string FarmerName { get; set; }

    public string FatherHusbandName { get; set; }

    public string Cnic { get; set; }     

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public string CellPhone { get; set; }

    public string PresentAddress { get; set; }

    public string PermanentAddress { get; set; }

    public int? EducationCode { get; set; }

    public int? MaleDependant { get; set; }

    public int? FemaleDependant { get; set; }

    public string AlternateName { get; set; }

    public string AlternateCellPhoneNo { get; set; }

    public string AlternateRelationshipwithFarmer { get; set; }

    public int? ReferalCode { get; set; }

    public string FarmerImage { get; set; }

    public string UnionCouncil { get; set; }

    public string MozaName { get; set; }

    public int? SmallAnimals { get; set; }

    public int? BigAnimals { get; set; }

    public int? Tractor { get; set; }

    public Guid? UserGuid { get; set; }

    public DistrictCodeModel DistrictCodeNavigation { get; set; }

    public TehsilCodeModel TehsilCodeNavigation { get; set; }     
   }
```

Another Model of the Tso User

```
public class TsoProfileModel
  {
    public long Tsoid { get; set; }

    public string Tsoname { get; set; }

    public string Cnic { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string CellPhone { get; set; }

    public string AlternateCellPhone { get; set; }

    public string Landline { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public string Tsoimage { get; set; }

    public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime? InsertionDate { get; set; }

    public string ActiveStatus { get; set; }

    public Guid? UserGuid { get; set; }

    public TbDistrictCode DistrictCodeNavigation { get; set; }

    public TbTehsilCode TehsilCodeNavigation { get; set; }

   }
```

This is my ViewModel in which i am trying to incorporrate my data of Farmer/Tso

```
   public class UserProfileInfo
   {
    public long? UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Cnic { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string AlternateCellPhone { get; set; }
    public string Landline { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string PresentAddress { get; set; }
    public string PermanentAddress { get; set; }
    public int? EducationCode { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? InsertionDate { get; set; }
    public string ActiveStatus { get; set; }
    public Guid? UserGuid { get; set; }
    public string FatherHusbandName { get; set; }
    public string CellPhone { get; set; }
    public int? MaleDependant { get; set; }
    public int? FemaleDependant { get; set; }
    public string AlternateName { get; set; }
    public string AlternateRelationshipwithFarmer { get; set; }
    public int? ReferalCode { get; set; }
    public string UnionCouncil { get; set; }
    public string MozaName { get; set; }
    public int? SmallAnimals { get; set; }
    public int? BigAnimals { get; set; }
    public int? Tractor { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public DistrictCodeModel DistrictCodeNavigation { get; set; }
    public TehsilCodeModel TehsilCodeNavigation { get; set; }    
    }
```

Below is the code I am trying to use.

```
if (User=="farmer")
        {


            var tbFarmerInfo = await 
   _farmerService.GetFarmerByCellPhone(cellno);
            var result = _Mapper.Map<UserProfileInfo>(tbFarmerInfo);

            result.UserId = tbFarmerInfo.FarmerId;
            result.UserName = tbFarmerInfo.FarmerName;
            result.image = tbFarmerInfo.FarmerImage;
            result.Role = "Farmer";
            response.Data = result;

            return response;
        }
  else if (User == "TSO")
   {
            string cellno = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == 
    ClaimTypes.Name).Value.TrimStart('0');


            var tbTsoInfo = await _tsoService.GetTSOByCellPhone(cellno);
            var result = _Mapper.Map<UserProfileInfo>(tbTsoInfo);

            result.UserId = tbTsoInfo.Tsoid;
            result.UserName = tbTsoInfo.Tsoname;
            result.image = tbTsoInfo.Tsoimage;
            result.Role = "TSO";
            response.Data = result;

           return response;
}
```

The expected result should be that both models can be mapped in the viewModel.
Like, if I map the FarmerProfile it should be mapped and if I want to map TsoProfile it should be mapped too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automapper - Multi object source and one destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544133/automapper-multi-object-source-and-one-destination)

Comment: @JSteward No, it's not. Please have a look at the models. Both models have different fields but I want to map them to one View Model.

Comment: Can you not handle that with your mapping configurations? Mapping different properties shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: I want it to be mapped in the same view model. So that I have to create only one model for future use rather than creating different models for the user profiles.