# Automapper, map from two unrelated sources

Tags: automapper

I am pulling data from a web API so I have no relationships between sources. I have a list of tickets from one method and a list of statuses from another.  The ticket model has a statusId field that relates to one of the statuses in the list of statues.  My TicketDTO has a StatusName field that I need to map from my previously populated list of statuses.

I have no idea how to do this in Automapper.  Any suggestions or examples?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to call `Map` multiple times and pass the same destination object.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544133/automapper-multi-object-source-and-one-destination) for possible solutions to your problem.